# How to get help from Allah when we are in danger?

Tags: allah, helping, blessings-of-allah

I am in extreme danger. All hope is turning to dust for me. I dont know what to do? How can I get help from Allah in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are safe. May Allah (SWT) make it easy for you and save you from harm, Aameen.

Whatever the danger might be, always keep your trust in Allah. When He is by your side, nothing can harm you on this earth.

In this situation, Dua is the best weapon for you! The following Dua is from Hadith:

Bismillaahil-lathee laa yadhurru ma’as-mihi shay’un fil-‘ardhi wa laa fis-samaa’i wa Huwas-Samee ‘ul- ‘Aleem.

In the Name of Allah, Who with His Name nothing can cause harm in the earth nor in the heavens, and He is the All-Hearing, the All-Knowing. (Recite three times in Arabic).

Source - https://sunnah.com/hisn/87

I would highly recommend you to recite **Hasbunallahu Wa Ni’mal Wakeel Ni’mal Maula Wa Ni’man Naseer** which in English translation means: Sufficient for us is Allah, and [He is] the best Disposer of affairs

This Dua was recited by Prophet Ibrahim (A.S). Have faith in Allah and keep reciting this Dua as much as you can.

Check out all the English translations & transliteration here - https://islamkazikr.com/hasbunallahu-wa-nimal-wakeel-meaning/

Always remember, nothing would harm you without the permission of Allah (SWT). Stay strong and have Tawakkul.

Additionally, take someone's help and avoid travelling or visiting the place where you know there could be danger ahead.

Disclosure: The above link has been published by me.

Comment: Many thanks for you.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, know that you must take every cause/protection/reason into account. Our prophet (PBUH) was asked about the camel to be left unleashed and relying on Allah, he said, no put the leash on, **then** rely on Allah.

As a rule of thumb: "Take every reason/cause/protection possible that you can as if they are everything, then rely on Allah as if these things are nothing".

Secondly, our prophet (PBUH) taught us some Zikr to say, for example:

I seek refuge in the Perfect Words of Allah from the evil of what He has created.

أَعُوذُ بِكَلِمات اللَّهِ التَّامَّاتِ مِنْ شَرِّ مَا خَلَقَ

O Allah, we make Thee our shield against them, and take refuge in Thee from their evils

اللهم إنَّا نجعلك في نحورهم، ونعوذ بك من شُرورهم

Additionally, be sure that nothing would harm or benefit you **ever**, without the permission of Allah.

Finally, our prophet (PBUH) said: If you die defending your family, or your money, then your are Shaheed (i.e. martyr).

So bulk up, avoid danger as much as possible, rely on Allah after taking every protection possible, say aforementioned zikr in addition to the morning and evening zikr, and don't let Satan take over you and disturb your heart because he loves that very much as per mentioned in Quran.

Final words, remember this verse:

Men said to them: "A great army is gathering against you": And frightened them: But it (only) increased their Faith: They said: "For us Allah sufficeth, and He is the best disposer of affairs."